# Can't hover 2nd ul from menu

Tags: html, css

I don't know where I have mistaken, I can't hover 2nd ul for the menu, where is solutions arrow down button, it doesn't stay active, when I hover it. I added `mobile_menu` class to separate it from other menus, and I can't find where I should put #mobile_menu to get it to work

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cve5kt5/)

HTML

```
<div id="mobile_menu">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu lines"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Solutions ￬</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pricing ￬</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About ￬</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Carrers</a></li> 
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I tried fiddle - it opens a sub-menu when I hover over "Solutions". It stays open until I move the mouse off it. Can you explain what it should do instead?

Comment: I guess he means, when sub menu is opened he is not able to move his mouse on sub-menu as sub-menu disappears immediately .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to *stabilize* the `hidden` `div` when its visible and being `hover`ed.

I have updated your [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cve5kt5/2/)

```
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
#mobile_menu ul li:hover > .hidden{
    display: block; /* make div display on hover*/
}
```